# How do I save the new dataframes that I am creating with my for-loop in R as individual files in a folder on my computer?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, export-to-csv, saving-data

I am importing some files from a folder on my computer, doing some calculations and then putting these calculations into new dataframes. I would like to save each of the new dataframes as csv files (filename_binomial data.csv) in a new folder on my computer. However, I am having difficulty doing so.

Here is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
parentdir<-"C:/Users/s2087070/Desktop/PhD/IAH Systematic Review"# root path to main folder
datadir<- paste(parentdir,"/New Folder",sep="") # directory containing original data files 

#set working directory
setwd(datadir)

#list the files in the directory
files<-list.files()

##Loop through the files
for(file in files){
  
  #dataname <-files[file]
  dataname<-strsplit(file,split='[.]')[[1]][1]
  
  #Load data
  data<-read.csv(file)
  data1<-data[,1:3]
  data1[,"Uninfected"]<-data1$num.tot-data1$num.inf
  new<-reframe(data1, Score = c(rep(1, num.inf), rep(0, Uninfected)), .by = inoc.size)
  new1<-data.frame(new)
  
  
  write.csv(new1, "C:/Users/s2087070/Desktop/PhD/IAH Systematic Review/Binomial 
  data/dataname_binomial data.csv")
  
}
```

I want to save the new files in a folder called "Binomial data" and I want the file names to be the original filename but with an added "_binomial data."

So if the original file was called "John1990.csv", the new file should be called "John1990_binomial data.csv"

Answer (score 3):

`dataname` is a variable that holds the actual name for the file name. You can use `paste0` to combine it with the path and suffix for storing:

```
write.csv(new1, paste0("C:/Users/s2087070/Desktop/PhD/IAH Systematic Review/Binomial data/", dataname, "_binomial data.csv"))
```

I'd recommend to not use spaces in paths/file names as it can lead to problems or difficulties e.g. when working on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

```
parentdir<-"C:/Users/s2087070/Desktop/PhD/IAH Systematic Review"

file <- "C:/Users/s2087070/Desktop/PhD/IAH Systematic Review/Binomial 
data/John1990.csv"

paste0(parentdir, "/Binomial data/", tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file)), "_binomial data.csv")

# [1] "C:/Users/s2087070/Desktop/PhD/IAH Systematic Review/Binomial data/John1990_binomial data.csv"
```